# How to add a control to a resource file in C# for localizing a winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resources, locale

I want to add culture to window application so that it can be used globally.
For this I want to use Only one Resource File.

Right now what I do is adds control manually to that file and reads them at page load.
I want this thing to become automated.

How should I proceed

Answer (score 1):

The .Net model is to use a different dll per culture, so if I understand correctly, you're not going to be able to use .NET i18n.